# Possible to use PHP to simulate an iFrame so I can access the DOM of a non hosted page?

Tags: php, dom, include, same-origin-policy

I'm working on a project where I would like to load the contents of one webpage (that I'm not hosting) into a webpage that I am hosting with the ability to access the DOM of the non-hosted page.

If anyone has any advice as to whether it's possible to achieve this, I'd love to hear some feedback. Maybe PHP isn't even the answer.  Maybe I'm going about this all wrong. I'm definitely open to any suggestions at this point!

Thanks for reading,
DJS

Comment: load the remote page html as curl and then just dump it inline directly into your page which will give you access to its dom

Comment: @Dave - he did that, and it is the only way, but there's another issue - the links on included page take people away from the mentioned "app". And that's a problem that's not that easy to solve.

Comment: easy fix as afxdesign has stated just use a regex on embedded links when you rewrite the dom before outputting in app

Answer (score 1):

You can use curl in PHP to load the webpage into a variable instead of an IFrame and then output the contents of the variable using PHP wrapped in your layout. In this way, the DOM for all of the content should be accessible with JavaScript.

Comment: Thanks ronnied.  I can curl a url into the page, however when I try to curl an IP address, I get nothing.  Here's the code I'm using:

`// Check for cURL
if( !function_exists( 'curl_init' ) ) die( 'cURL is not installed.' );

// Create a cURL resource handler (cURL Handler = ch)
$c = curl_init();

// Set options
$c = curl_init('http://192.168.1.xx/u/r/l');

curl_exec($c);

$output = curl_exec( $c );

curl_close( $c );

echo $output;
`

Answer (score 0):

As ronnied has answered, you can use CURL to load the page. You can update all the links by using a simple regex query on the loaded page. The following code should point you in the right direction in particular look up preg_replace and preg_replace_callback:

```
//Regular expression to deal with links...
function replaceCallback($match){ 
    $url = $match[3];
    ...
    return $match[1].$match[2].$replacement.$match[4];
}

//$html is curl'd page contents
$pattern = "/(<a.*?href\s*=\s*)('|\")(.*?)('|\")/i";
$html = preg_replace_callback($pattern,'replaceCallback',$html);
```

Regular expressions are hard to get your head around. But when you do you will be highly rewarded as they are very powerful...